# Convert String to Double and put it into a Stack

Tags: java

I have this expression, for example:
`400 2.11 +`
I try to push real numbers into a stack, when i do that, it shows me an error in this part of code

```
ch = input.charAt(j);
if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' || ch == '.')
    temp = temp + ch;

else if (ch == ' ') {
    x = Double.parseDouble(temp);
    theStack.push(x);
    temp = "";
}
else {

...

public void push(double j) {
        stackArray[++top] = j;
    }
```

This is the message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1011)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at ParsePost.doParse(ParsePost.java:26)
    at InfixApp.main(InfixApp.java:21)
```

Comment: I have a class `StackY`. and `theStack` is an object from `StackY` when I should put the numbers.

Comment: maybe you can print `temp`

Comment: Post ur push method to check . And is do parse ur custom method. If yes post that  alsi

Comment: Try debugging a little bit.  You could start by printing the value of `input.charAt(j)` and adding a print statement inside your _if statement_ to make sure you're actually adding characters to temp.  I don't see any evidence that you're iterating over all the characters in `input`.

Comment: Check my input value. I've changed it!

Answer (score 1):

This is an error regarding to empty String which is clearly mentioned in the error.Here The value of 'temp' variable is empty.And `Double.parseDouble(temp)` is not able to parse an empty String.So it's throwing an exception.To make it work you have to give a float which is in the form of String which can be Parseable for this function.

Comment: Why is it empty? What do you mean by giving a float?

Comment: My best guess, for your question of "why is temp empty?" is that there is a problem with your code in populating temp with characters. I would step it through a debugger to see if it's doing what you think it is. You should also put an if statement on the temp String to make sure the String length is not 0

Answer (score 1):

If you know the separation character between numbers, maybe you can use the `split(String regex)` function.
In this case, once you've specified the separation character, is your duty check the `String[]` returned by `split` and find the arithmetical symbol.

I wrote this simple class for test what I say:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StringParsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Simple string to split
        String str = "444 6.12 +";
        String[] values = str.split(" ");
        ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            //I check only for +
            if(!values[i].contains("+")) {
                Double d = Double.parseDouble(values[i]);
                arr.add(d);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
            //Add 1 to number for verify the correctness
            System.out.println("Double: "+(arr.get(i)+1.0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you went wrong with temp..i think temp is empty..

```
if(temp.trim().length()>0){
   x = Double.parseDouble(temp);
   theStack.push(x);

}
```

Comment: I know! But how to fix it? I can't! I don't like to test if it's full or empty ; i must have the number in `temp`

Answer (score 0):

```
ch = input.charAt(j);
                    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' || ch == '.')
                        temp = temp + ch;

                    else if (ch == ' ') {
                        if (null != temp && temp.trim().length()>0) {
                            x = Double.parseDouble(temp.trim());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Case where string is empty
                        }
                        theStack.push(x);
                        temp = "";
                    }
```

Try this hope it helps.

Comment: I like it to be full, not empty :(

Comment: Well can you please share some more info.. What is criteria for the input ? How it is being taken from the user

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code with proper initialization, and push the exact input String and it works fine, I have added a FOR loop though.

Just like the suggestions above, the problem is you are trying to convert an empty String to double.

double x = Double.parseDouble(temp);

Comment: Check my input value. I've changed it!